# Why SocialSharing plugin not work (phonegap)

Tags: cordova

I use button in html tag and write script on click:

```
function social_share()
{
            window.plugins.socialsharing.share("Blog Post Title","Post Summery",null,"http://qnimate.com",function(result){
                alert('result: ' + result);
            }, function(result){
                alert('error: ' + result);
            });
 }
```

---

It generate error while clicking on button.

> "E/Web Console(1218): Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no
>   method 'share' at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:42"